# Is there any way to migrate a project and its tasks from an instance of Jira to another one?

Tags: migration, jira

We have a project (let's call it `ProjectToMigrate`) that was created a few years ago under under a given JIRA instance (let's call it `Jira-A`). It contains a few thousand tasks, in various states. Roughly 10 users are linked to this project.

The instance `Jira-A` also contains other projects, and other users, completely unrelated with `ProjectToMigrate`.

This project is going to be transferred to another legal entity that uses its own JIRA instance (`Jira-B`). In this instance, we have several pre-existing projects and users that we should keep.

Is there any way to migrate `ProjectToMigrate` from `Jira-A` to `Jira-B`, including all its tasks, components, versions, related users, and other pertaining pieces of information? 
Any way would be fine: export/import, SQL, plug-in, or any other. 
The only objective is to have `ProjectToMigrate` in `Jira-B` as if it had been created in this instance from day 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is there: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA041/Restoring+a+Project+from+Backup?clicked=jirahelp